# knex - Raw query execute - how to get the db result along with data type

Tags: node.js, knex.js, node-oracledb

while execute the raw query using knex (oracle) npm, how to get the data type of the each column along with the result.

```
select name,age from customers;
```

when we execute this as raw query using nodejs we can get the selected columns as array result.

> rows:[{name: 'SAM', age: 35},{name:'IMRAN',age:25}]

I need data and also the **data type** of the each column along with the result of the raw query.

Expected Result:

> { "result": { "rows": [{ "name": "SAM", "age": 35 }, { "name":
> "IMRAN", "age": 25 }], "columns_details": { "name": "varchar 2(32)",
> "age": "number(2)" } } }

Is there any option is available to get the above result?pls suggest me to get this requirement.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is your best bet: https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1135#issuecomment-293405104. Because, (I think), you are trying to query the data schema with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `knex.raw` queries some drivers might return also datatype information. Knex doesn't provide any special support for that though, so you need to check node-oracledb documentation how to get that column metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue using postgres as the db. The db results of a `SELECT` query are in the `.rows` key of what is returned from `.raw()`

Another issue is that raw queries don't automatically *camelCase* the results so I also had to deal with that.

I ended up making a little async utility function to run the raw query, extract the results, and *camelCase* the keys.

```
import { camelCase, mapKeys } from 'lodash';

export const rawQuery = async (query) => {
  const result = await knex.raw(query);
  return result && result.rows
    ? result.rows.map((el) => mapKeys(el, (_, key) => camelCase(key)))
    : [];
};
```

The parameter `query` is a string containing an arbitrary SQL SELECT query. This function doesn't allow for variables to be passed into the query but that would be a simple extension.